# Is zap docker able to generate .xml report?

Tags: python, docker, automation, zap

I am un-able to generating .xml report when i am running zap docker command.
Is their any way to generate .xml format report using zap docker.

Here is my running zap docker command for .html format.

```
docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/zap/wrk/:rw -t owasp/zap2docker-weekly zap-baseline.py -t http://www.example.com -g gen.conf -r zaphtmlreport.html
```

Somewhere i find, for xml we need to change only file format. Then i am using below command for xml format which is not working:

```
docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/zap/wrk/:rw -t owasp/zap2docker-weekly zap-baseline.py -t http://www.example.com -g gen.conf -r zapxmlreport.xml
```

Please help me to generate .xml report file.

Comment: any idea what is the reason for the report not being generated at all ? :) yes, all perms are set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answered on the ZAP developer group https://groups.google.com/d/msg/zaproxy-users/NDpy-AjWCwg/iEKVYh1gAgAJ

For completeness - just use an unsupported option like '-h' and the script will output all of the valid options.

One of which is '-x report_xml     file to write the full ZAP XML report'

Comment: Oh my bad luck its not help me, i am not find any -x option in help. 
Please check https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/zaproxy-users/NDpy-AjWCwg/iEKVYh1gAgAJ my reply. :-(

Comment: Thanks, its working. I run this command on diff. centos server and its working for me.

Answer (score 1):

Now, my running commands are:

**For html report:**

```
docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/zap/wrk/:rw -t owasp/zap2docker-weekly zap-baseline.py -t http://www.example.com/ -r report_html
```

**And for xml report:**

```
docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/zap/wrk/:rw -t owasp/zap2docker-weekly zap-baseline.py -t http://champagn.netsolutions.in/ -x report_html
```